# Construction of K(G,1) from a presentation complex

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group,

$$ G = \langle s_1, \ldots, s_n \mid r_1, \ldots, r_m \rangle.$$

Given such a presentation, one constructs the presentation complex $\mathcal{P}$ with a single vertex, by attaching an edge for each generator $s_i$, and a 2-cell for every relator so that the attaching map "reads-off" the relator word $r_j$.

Suppose that $G$ is of type $F_n$. This means that there exists a $K(G,1)$ complex with a finite $n$-skeleton. When is it the case that such a $K(G,1)$ can be obtained from $\mathcal{P}$ by possibly adding cells of higher dimensions? What are the possible obstructions?

Comment: I think you can always do this. Did you check Ross Geoghegan's book "Topological Methods in Group Theory"?

Comment: I have a vague memory that there are some "exotic" presentations of type F groups that have its relation module (second homotopy group of this particular presentation complex) not finitely generated, although I cannot remember whether this is actually true, or where did I read this.

Comment: It would be very surprising if your claim is actually true, because there are presentations of finitely presented groups that have infinitely many relations which are not a consequence of any finite subset.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Geoghegan's book shows that one can always complete the presentation complex to a K(G,1) by adding higher dimensional cells, but there's no guarantee that you are adding a finite number of cells in each dimension

Comment: @xsnl yes, I had a feeling something like this might be the problem. Could you give me an example of such presentations? And what characterises  f.p. groups which can admit such presentations (this seems like a difficult question)?

Comment: The fact that "one can always complete the presentation complex to a K(G,1) by adding higher dimensional cells" is a triviality. From what I remember, R.G. proved in his book something nontrivial in this direction (going under the name "trading cells") and I think (but I might be misremembering) he proved what you asked; he used this to argue that type $F_\infty$ (or $F$?) is quasi-isometry invariant.